# How to replace Tablayout's current fragment with detail fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

I have a parent fragment containing TabLayout and ViewPager. The TabLayout has 5 tabs (fragments) managed by FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

And some fragments have child fragments. So when user click some labels, I have to open detail fragment.

How to replace current tab fragment with detail fragment or add new fragment to tab?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: please provide code your code.. if it is just for fragment replace you can do it by `FragmentTransaction`

Comment: Implement Your child fragments exactly as you do in Activity. Only use 'getChildFragmentManager()' instead